# Populate HTML table with jquery get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Morning all,
I perform the php mysqli to get the top 5 counted countries in sql. Then I use jquery get to get the data from the php script. In the end, I want to populate the HTML table with get jquery. I will only get 5 countries however i tried populating the html table with those data and the output is shown below.

```
malaysia united states united kindgom singapore netherlands
```

gettopfive.php

```
<?php

        include 'config.php';
        $con = mysqli_connect ($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword) or die ('Error in connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

        //Select the particular database and link to the connection
        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($con, $dbname ) or die('Select dbase error '. mysqli_error());
        //Make A SQL Query and link to the connection

        $topfivecountries = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `country.src` FROM `attackview` WHERE `device.type`='snort' AND `country.src` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `country.src` ORDER by count(*) DESC LIMIT 5");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($topfivecountries))
        {
            echo $row["country.src"]. "\n";
        }
        mysqli_free_result($topfivecountries);
        mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

output from the php script

```
malaysia 
united states 
united kindgom 
singapore 
netherlands
```

jquery get app.js

```
$.get({
            url: 'gettopfive.php',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: gettopfive
        });

function getfive(val) {
        $('#getfive').html(val);
    }
```

html code

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<table id="getfive">
<tr><td></td><tr>
<tr><td></td><tr>
<tr><td></td><tr>
<tr><td></td><tr>
<tr><td></td><tr>
</table>
```

My output is not exactly what I want
i want something like this.

```
malaysia 
united states
 united kindgom 
singapore
 netherlands
```

Is it the correct method to get the data??? If it is wrong mind explainig to me on how to do it?? Thank you..

Comment: can you post the output from the php script (database call) here so that I can work from there ?.

Comment: I think you better use `$.load()` to accomplish your need better than `$.get()`

Comment: @sbr i have updated it. you can check above

Comment: @Azhar just to confirm the result is a multi line string, correct ?

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda, may I know why you suggest of using $.load() instead of $.get()

Comment: @Azhar because it seems you have no any get request parameter, so `$.load()` is more effective and it get the data as HTML. You can do like: `$('#getfive').load('gettopfive.php');` to fill the table, you should change your line in gettopfive.php from `echo $row["country.src"]. "\n";` to html markup like `echo "<td>".$row["country.src"]."</td>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending @nirnay's answer by creating the country array from the string. Also fixed the callback function name.

```
   $.get({
        url: 'gettopfive.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: getfive
    });

    function getfive(val) {
        var countryArray = val.split('\n');
        countryArray.forEach(function(country){
            $('#getfive').append('<tr><td>'+country+'</td></tr>') 
        });
    }
```

Comment: where did u get the 'country' from

Comment: @Azhar country is the argument that is being passed by the forEach to the callback function. so you don't need to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the table from the script only after success of the ajax request. Send your result as an ARRAY not as a STRING. Remove table from the html and put a div with id as 'result' in which you can show you result.

change your `$('#getfive').html(val);` as

```
$('#result').html('<table id="getfive"></table>'); 
    result.forEach(function(item) { 
    $('#getfive table').append('<tr><td>'+item+'</td></tr>') 
});
```

Comment: Hi all i input the code like this function gettopfive(val) {
  $('#result').html('<table id="getfive"></table>'); 
  result.forEach(function(item) { 
  $('#getfive table').append('<tr><td>'+item+'</td></tr>') 
  });
 }

Comment: then i got the error which states result.foreach is not a function

Comment: can you explain to me on what does the result from the foreach represent

Comment: @Azhar forEach works on Arrays. It will execute the code block for each entry in the array. You are getting the error since there is no Array called result. For more info on forEach read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach